# mysql ranking users by score/points

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

below query cool for normal users ranking by score but I need a query with same rank result for same scores in table

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank,score, user_id FROM site_crossword_members ORDER BY score DESC 
) as tmp;
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that your given query even works properly? I recall `ORDER BY` to be done after `SELECT`, thus making your rank sort by `ID ASC` or similiar.

```
SELECT user_id, 
    CASE WHEN @score != score THEN @rank := @rank + 1 ELSE @rank END AS rank,
    @score := score AS dummy_value
FROM (  SELECT score, user_id
        FROM site_crossword_members, 
            (SELECT @rank := 0, @score := NULL) AS vars
        ORDER BY score DESC) AS h
```

**Shortened version:**

```
SELECT user_id, 
    @rank := @rank + (@score != score) AS rank,
    @score := score AS dummy_value
FROM (  SELECT score, user_id
        FROM site_crossword_members, 
            (SELECT @rank := 0, @score := NULL) AS vars
        ORDER BY score DESC) AS h
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query (version with variables) -

```
SET @rank = 0;
SET @score = NULL;

SELECT
  rank, score, user_id
FROM (
  SELECT
    score,
    user_id,
    IF(@score = score, @rank := @rank + 1, @rank := 1) AS rank,
    @score := score
  FROM site_crossword_members
  ORDER BY score DESC
) t;
```

Comment: The question could be read in several says. Yours works when needed to reset the rank upon new score, however he wanted people with equal score to share ranks.